# ssh bash receive variable from a remote file

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to read the variable from a remote file over SSH and compare it. But I get a variable in the wrong format. how to do it correctly?

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    pass='dpassspass'
    user='root@10.10.19.18'
    IP="10.2.1.41"
    path=/sys/variable/serv
    #not work## No such file or directory# write=$(sshpass -p $ovhpass ssh -t $user echo "$IP" > $path)
    sshpass -p $pass ssh -t $user  << EOF
    echo "$IP" > $path
    EOF
    my_var=$(sshpass -p $pass ssh -t $user "cd /sys_ovh; ./serv.bash")
    echo mystart-"$my_var"-myend
    read=$(sshpass -p $pass ssh -t $user cat $path)
    echo start-"$read"-end
    echo start-"$IP"-end
    if [ "$read" == "$IP" ]; then 
    echo "run"
    fi
```

output:

```
Connection to 10.10.19.18 closed.
-myendt-10.2.1.41
Connection to 10.10.19.18 closed.
-endt-10.2.1.41
start-10.2.1.41-end
```

Where I make a mistake? How to take data from the SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vars `my_var` and `read` are filled with a string ending with '\r', telling echo to go back to the first column. I think this is a problem with your local script. You can correct that with

```
tr -d "\r" < myfile > myfile2
```

Comment: I change  to read=$(sshpass -p $pass ssh -t $user cat $path16 | tr -d "\r") and all work fine. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem comes from using unquoted here documents for the commands. You should properly understand in which order the shell interprets these contructs.

```
ssh remote cmd >file
```

executes `cmd` remotely, but first redirects the output from the `ssh` command to the local `file`.

```
ssh remote "cmd >’$file'"
```

The quotes cause the redirection to be part of the `remote` command line. The variable `file` is interpreted first, by the local shell, though.

```
ssh remote 'cmd >"$file"`
```

The single quotes prevent the local shell from modifying the command before sending it. Thus,  he variable interpolation and the redirection are both handled by the `remote` shell, in this order.

So your commented-out "not work" command could easily be fixed with proper quoting. However, it will be much more elegant and efficient to use a single remote session, and execute all the commands in one go. Mixing the local variable `IP` with remote variables calls for some rather elaborate escaping, though. A major simplification would be to pass the value on standard input, so that the entire remote script can be single quoted.

```
#!/bin/bash 
pass='dpassspass'
user='root@10.10.19.18'
IP="10.2.1.41"
result=$(echo "$IP" |
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh -t "$user" '
    path=/sys/variable/serv
    cat > "$path"
    cd /sys_ovh
    ./serv.bash
    cat "$path"')
echo mystart-"${result%$'\n'*}"-myend
echo start-"${result#*$'\n'}"-end
echo start-"$IP"-end
if [ "${result#*$'\n'}" == "$IP" ]; then 
  echo "run"
fi
```

The output from the remote shell is two lines; we pick it apart by using the shell's prefix and suffix substitution operators.